# How to set up different parameter in a Composite Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

for my develop i want to use the component-pattern because a component is part of another component.

But there is one problem. The components need different parameters in the `run`-function (which must be implement).

Does someone have a idea how to realize it?

Example:

```java
   public abstract class componsite{
       Componente(){...}
       public void run(Object object1){......}
  }
  public class firstComponent extends composite{
       ....
       public void run(Object object1){......}
       @Override
  }
  public class secondComponent extends composite{
       ....
       @Override
       public void run(Object object1,Different Object object2){......}
  }
```

Greetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java's Varargs as part of the Composite interface

```
public class secondComponent extends composite{
   ....
   @Override
   public void run(Object... object){......}
}
```

Comment: thank you. I hope, i can write for each run Function a java doc :)

Comment: Now i have a question to the varargs....How can i find out which kind of object it is?

Comment: `Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();` will be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the Visitor pattern.  This allows for an elegant strongly typed solution that avoids type checking using `instanceof` or downcasting.

```
public interface ComponentVisitor {
  void visitFirstComponent(FirstComponent fc);

  void visitSecondComponent(SecondComponent sc);
}

public class ComponentVisitorImpl implements ComponentVisitor {
  public void visitFirstComponent(FirstComponent fc) {    
    fc.firstComponentSpecifiedMethod(a, b, c);
    // Make a call *back* to FirstComponent passing in appropriate parameters.
  }
}
```

Then within each Component's `run()` method you simply call the relevant visitor method which will then make a call back into the component with the relevant parameters; e.g.

```
public class FirstComponent extends Component {
  public void run(ComponentVisitor cv) {
    cv.visitFirstComponent(this);
  }
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that the logic can be difficult to follow.